# Bundler says I have the wrong ruby version, but all my checks say it is correct

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

`bundle` results in the error message "Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0"

Yet all my checks indicate that I have the right version of ruby. (And, yes, I've run `rbenv rehash`)

```sh
rbenv local
# 2.3.0
which bundle
# /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin/bundle
rbenv which bundle
# /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle
which ruby
# /home/me/.rbenv/shims/ruby
rbenv which ruby
# /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby
rbenv which irb
# /home/me/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/irb
rbenv whence rackup
# 2.3.0
ruby -v
# ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]
bundle exec ruby -v
# ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]

bundle -v
# Bundler version 2.1.4
```

What else is there to check?

This is my workstation (not a server), and it was working fine until this morning.

Comment: `bundle env` might give you some more information. The top section, `## Environment`, is what you'd be interested in.

Comment: Could you fix the issue already?

Comment: @ThomasKoppensteiner sorry. I did get past this, but I don't recall what the culprit was. Let that me a lesson to me to document right away.